# Is the syntax different in CodeDOM?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, codedom

**This question is related to Visual Basic .NET**

I'm trying to compile some code using CodeDOM. I've compiled it in the normal Visual Studio and it's fine. But when I compile using CodeDOM it throws the 'Expression Expected' error at this piece of code:

```
Dim O As System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation
O.Post(Sub() OnExceptionThrown(New Exception("EX MESSAGE")), Nothing)
```

So my question is; is the syntax different in CodeDOM?

Comment: Using Sub in a lambda expression was not supported until VS2010 and .NET 4.  So a rough guess is that you are targeting an earlier .NET framework version and thus are using an older compiler.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Would you know if there's another way to write it to make it work in 2.0?

Comment: I would know.  Try not to get stuck on a 9 year old version of free software.

Comment: Oh I'm not. I use the 2010 version of Visual Studio but I compile to 2.0 to make the application more portable.

Comment: @HansPassant That can't be it, because the exact same code compiles in Visual Studio just fine (under the 2.0 framework)

Comment: MSBuild uses the 4.0 compiler, even if you target 2.0, using the /langversion option.